# Should I keep macroses like `_In_`, `_Out_` in typedef of pointer to a function?

Tags: c, winapi, typedef

I need to load WinAPI function dynamically. Therefore I define a new type - pointer to a function.
Should I keep macroses like `_In_`, `_Out_` in my typedef?

For example WinAPI function: `BOOL WINAPI CloseHandle(_In_ HANDLE hObject);`

How to define pointer to this function?

- `typedef BOOL (WINAPI * CloseHandlePtr)(_In_ HANDLE hObject);`
- `typedef BOOL (WINAPI * CloseHandlePtr)(HANDLE hObject);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those macros are part of Microsoft Source Annotation Language (SAL, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh916383.aspx ) that are meant to help as annotations for human readers and code analysis tools.

Your typedefs will work without them. As function pointer typedefs are complex enough already, one cold argue to leave them out.

On the other hand leaving them out could prevent e.g. Visual Studio code analysis from finding a bug in your code.